# Change the color of UIView Object Reference while it is animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, core-graphics

I have a drawn a view in my xib file. I want it to change its color while it is being animated. Animation is working. But I cant find to change the color of the Object. 
Please help me with this. I'm totally new to ios.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please add some sample code of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write Following Code at Your `UIView` Animation process.

```
YourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^ {

    //other animations

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can animate color like that (with animateWithDuration...). You would have to use a timer and iterate over a series of colors. You could use colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha: for instance, and increment the hue value.